# Create a Query with Conditional Column Selections

Tags: google-sheets

** Edited to include sample sheet**

I am looking to create a query that has some conditional column selections within it. I need the query to reference and return several fixed columns *as well as* one headed with today's date. I need the query to return columns A and B always, and then the column that is headed with Today's Date. We are having someone open a living document each week and reference/print the Query chart that ONlY includes that day's information.

See sample data sheet here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UhsupUoLT3l4Heq2c1pWUmwxX1cHuV0WzWNUwiB3Yo0/edit?usp=sharing

Here is what I've come up with so far, but I can't figure out how to remove the "C" references instead of having them be today's date.

=QUERY(A:F,"select A,B,E where E>0")

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `and desired result`. Please edit the question to include your expected result.

Comment: `I need the query to reference and return several fixed columns as well as one headed with today's date.` As noted by the Community Bot, it is `hard to tell exactly what you're asking`; would you please explain your scenario and the purpose of your query. Regarding dates, today = 17 Jan 2024 but the sample data doesn't include this date; what outcome are you expected in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this using the `FILTER` function:

```cpp
=FILTER(A:F,{1,1,C1:F1=TODAY()})
```

[image]

If you want to do it using `QUERY`, you could try something like this:

```cpp
=QUERY(A:F,"select Col1,Col2,Col"&XMATCH(TODAY(),A1:F1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I need the Query to only return rows within today's column that are >0. How do I add that into the formula?

Comment: you can wrap another QUERY around the formula. For example `QUERY(formula,"where Col3>0")`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm super new to these formulas- how would I write that? Would it be =QUERY(A:F,"select Col1,Col2,Col"&XMATCH(TODAY(),A1:F1), "where Col"&XMATCH(TODAY(),A1:F1)>0)

Comment: `=QUERY(QUERY(A:F,"select Col1,Col2,Col"&XMATCH(TODAY(),A1:F1)),"where Col3>0")`

Comment: Thank you so much- this worked perfectly. 

If you can help me learn why you used "Col1" vs. just "A" in the formula I looked up and understand the rest!

Comment: it's because getting the index of a column is much easier than getting its address.